# Error while rendering buffer in chartjs-node-canvas

Tags: node.js, excel, chart.js

I am trying to render a line graph image using the **renderToBuffer** method in **ChartJSNodeCanvas**. It works fine locally, but when I have deployed I am getting the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?